# Start spring boot jar file as part of tomcat start

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

There is a way I can start the spring boot jar file as part of tomcat start(catalina.bat start).

I have a spring cloud api gateway which does not support war file deployment.

In a bare metal box, I have installed the tomcat, and as part of deployment I have converted all microservice into war file and able to deploy it into tomcat/webapp folder and up and running.

As spring cloud api gateway does not support war file, I kept this application with embed tomcat.

Now I need this jar file as well get started along with the tomcat [catalina.bat start].

In tomcat I have seen there is something  shared.loader option in catalina.properties file.
I have kept the jar file in below path as shown below and when I try to start it, jar file is not getting picked up.

[image]

Need to know if there is a way to start the spring boot application [jar file] as part of tomcat [catalina.bat start] start.

Comment: check here please. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy

Comment: @muhammedozbilici spring cloud api gateway does not support war file. So I need cloud api application get started as jar file along with tomcat [catalina start] automatically along with other microservice application.